# comarison betwen normal array against associative array

Tags: php, function

*problem is*

```
$array=(p,u,s,h,p,a)

$array1(p=>1,u=>4,s=>6,h=>8,p=>1,a=>5)
```

or

```
$array1(1=>p,4=>u,6=>s,8=>h,1=>p,5=>a)
```

if i compare $array to $array1 how can i get $array1 key or value.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($array1 as $key => $val) {
    // $key will contain p on the first iteration, then u on the next, etc...
}
```

Comment: function SwapArray($Array){
    $Values = array();
    while(list($Key,$Val) = each($Array))
        $Values[$Val] = $Key;
    return $Values;
}
$array1 = array('a','a','b','c');
 $array2 = array('a' => 0, 'b' => 1, 'c' => 2, 'd' => 3); if compare two of arrays how can i get  value of $array2 after that the values must be find out total of values.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little confusing, but I think you are talking about `array_keys()` and `array_values()`.

Comment: function SwapArray($Array){
    $Values = array();
    while(list($Key,$Val) = each($Array))
        $Values[$Val] = $Key;
    return $Values;
}
$array1 = array('a','a','b','c');
 $array2 = array('a' => 0, 'b' => 1, 'c' => 2, 'd' => 3); if compare two of arrays how can i get  value of $array2 after that the values must be find out total of values.